# finding lowest and highest value from multiple column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql database from where I have to get the lowest and highest value from multiple column by indicator_id,

table data data like

```
Indicator_id    threshold_id    colour  Strat_value End_value
2004                1            Green      2            2
2004                2            Amber      1            1
2004                3            Red        0            0
2004                4            Black      -1           -10
```

I have used the following code but not getting correct result

```
select indicator_id,  
       least(Start_value,End_value) low, 
       greatest(Start_value,End_value) high
from shrewd_db.threshold
group by id_indicator;
```

any help would be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I am getting out put like indeicator_id = 2004, low = 2 and high = 2

Comment: Yes, but what should be the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/JVCT29018)**

```
SELECT `Indicator_id`, 
        LEAST(MIN(`Strat_value`), MIN(`End_value`)) as smallest,
        GREATEST(MAX(`Strat_value`), MAX(`End_value`)) as biggest
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `Indicator_id`
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]